# How to add a barrier in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a layout which I have created using RelativeLayout and LinearLayout. I am having an issue creating it back in ConstraintLayout. I have found that my problem can be solved using a barrier but I am finding it very difficult.

Expected Output :

[image: Expected Output]

My Output :

[image: MyOutput]

Here is my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/tracmor">

     <ScrollView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:fillViewport="true">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_3sdp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/grey"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_3sdp"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <!--For Asset-->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cvAsset"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_3sdp"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/_3sdp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cvShipping"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="45">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/clAsset"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivAsset"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:src="@drawable/assets"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvAssetStats"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_20sdp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:text="@string/assetstatistics"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dashboard_Title"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivAsset"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvAssetNo"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:textColor="@color/blue"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dashboard_Count"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/vline"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivAsset"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tvAssetStats"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvAssetStats" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvAssetDetail"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_20sdp"
                        android:textColor="@color/blue"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dashboard_Count"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/vline"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvAssetStats" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/vline"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_1sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/dashboard_Count"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:background="@color/grey2"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvAssetDetail"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvAssetNo"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvAssetStats" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <!--For Shipping-->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cvShipping"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_3sdp"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/_3sdp"

                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cvReceipt"

                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cvAsset"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="45">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/clShipping"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"

                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivShipping"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:src="@drawable/shipping"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvShippingStats"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_20sdp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:text="@string/shippingactivity"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dashboard_Title"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivShipping"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvShippingNo"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:textColor="@color/blue"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dashboard_Count"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/vlineS"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivShipping"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tvShippingStats"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvShippingStats" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvShipppingDetail"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_20sdp"
                        android:textColor="@color/blue"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dashboard_Count"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/vlineS"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvShippingStats" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/vlineS"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_1sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/dashboard_Count"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:background="@color/grey2"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvShipppingDetail"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvShippingNo"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvShippingStats" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <!--For Receipt-->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cvReceipt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_3sdp"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/_3sdp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cvkb"

                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cvShipping"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="45">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/clReceipt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"

                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivReceipt"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:src="@drawable/receiving"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvReceiptStats"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_20sdp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:text="@string/receivingactivity"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dashboard_Title"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivReceipt"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvReceivingNo"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:textColor="@color/blue"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dashboard_Count"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/vlineR"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivReceipt"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tvReceiptStats"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvReceiptStats" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvReceivingDetail"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_20sdp"
                        android:textColor="@color/blue"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dashboard_Count"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/vlineR"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvReceiptStats" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/vlineR"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_1sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/dashboard_Count"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:background="@color/grey2"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvReceivingDetail"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvReceivingNo"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvReceiptStats" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


                <!--For Knowledgebase-->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cvkb"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_3sdp"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/_3sdp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cvReceipt"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="65">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/clKb"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivKnowledgebase"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/knowledge"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/knowledgebase"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dashboard_Title"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivKnowledgebase" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


            <!-- <View
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/cvkb"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cvkb"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cvReceipt"
                            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".02" />
            -->
            <!--For RequestSupport-->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cvRS"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_3sdp"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/_3sdp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cvReceipt"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="65"

                >

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/clRS"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivRequestSupport"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/request"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/requestsupport"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dashboard_Title"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivRequestSupport" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <!-- <android.support.constraint.Barrier
                            android:id="@+id/barrier"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            app:barrierDirection="end"
                            app:constraint_referenced_ids="cvkb,cvRS" />
            -->

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

EveryThing is almost correct except for request support CardView

**Edit :** When I rotate the device the view still remains constraint but the layout is compressed and constraint layout does not show some images and text at first launch when I redirect to other fragment then it shows all images and text. [landscape](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iqReIxqcCkDaoqSoscW2CDc5T8z4Jp3Y/view)
[firstlaunch](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x_S-IfQEZSUBtupD1GXX3h3GAMVmnJI_/view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your `CardView` which have `android:id="@+id/cvRS"` to be like this

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cvRS"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_3sdp"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/_3sdp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/cvkb"// this do the trick
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/cvkb" //
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="65"
                >
```

**Edit :** check the full layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/tracmor">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_3sdp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/grey"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_3sdp"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <!--For Asset-->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cvAsset"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_3sdp"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/_3sdp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cvShipping"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="45">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/clAsset"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivAsset"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/assets"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvAssetStats"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
                        android:text="@string/assetstatistics"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dashboard_Title"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tvAssetNo"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivAsset"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivAsset"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvAssetNo"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="testValue1"
                        android:textColor="@color/blue"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dashboard_Count"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/vline"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tvAssetStats"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvAssetStats" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvAssetDetail"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="testValue1"
                        android:textColor="@color/blue"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dashboard_Count"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tvAssetNo"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/vline"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tvAssetNo" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/vline"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_1sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/dashboard_Count"
                        android:background="@color/grey2"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tvAssetNo"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tvAssetNo" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <!--For Shipping-->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cvShipping"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_3sdp"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/_3sdp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cvReceipt"

                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cvAsset"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="45">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/clShipping"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"

                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivShipping"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/shipping"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvShippingStats"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
                        android:text="@string/shippingactivity"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dashboard_Title"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tvShippingNo"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivShipping"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivShipping"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvShippingNo"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:text="testValue2"
                        android:textColor="@color/blue"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dashboard_Count"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/vlineS"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tvShippingStats"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvShippingStats" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvShipppingDetail"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="testValue2"
                        android:textColor="@color/blue"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dashboard_Count"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tvShippingNo"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/vlineS"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tvShippingNo" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/vlineS"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_1sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/dashboard_Count"
                        android:background="@color/grey2"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tvShippingNo"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tvShippingNo" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <!--For Receipt-->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cvReceipt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_3sdp"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/_3sdp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cvkb"

                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cvShipping"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="45">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/clReceipt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"

                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivReceipt"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/receiving"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvReceiptStats"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
                        android:text="@string/receivingactivity"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dashboard_Title"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tvReceivingNo"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivReceipt"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivReceipt"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvReceivingNo"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:text="testValue3"
                        android:textColor="@color/blue"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dashboard_Count"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/vlineR"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tvReceiptStats"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvReceiptStats" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvReceivingDetail"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_20sdp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="testValue3"
                        android:textColor="@color/blue"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dashboard_Count"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tvReceivingNo"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/vlineR"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tvReceivingNo" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/vlineR"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_1sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/dashboard_Count"
                        android:background="@color/grey2"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tvReceivingNo"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tvReceivingNo" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


            <!--For Knowledgebase-->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cvkb"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_3sdp"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/_3sdp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cvReceipt"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="65">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/clKb"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_4sdp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivKnowledgebase"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/knowledge"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tv_knowledge"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_knowledge"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/knowledgebase"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dashboard_Title"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivKnowledgebase" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


            <!-- <View
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/cvkb"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cvkb"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cvReceipt"
                            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".02" />
            -->
            <!--For RequestSupport-->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cvRS"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_3sdp"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/_3sdp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/cvkb"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/cvkb"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="65"

                >

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/clRS"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_4sdp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivRequestSupport"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/request"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tv_support"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_support"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dashboard_Title"
                        android:text="@string/requestsupport"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivRequestSupport" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <!-- <android.support.constraint.Barrier
                            android:id="@+id/barrier"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            app:barrierDirection="end"
                            app:constraint_referenced_ids="cvkb,cvRS" />
            -->

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</ScrollView>
```

check this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o91Lc.jpg) for the final output

Comment: Thankyou.Solved my issue. I have another issue my layout is not working when I rotate the screen.Am I using correct practices in design

Comment: What is the issue with landscape layout, I think your constraint are right.

Comment: here is the screenshot of [landscape](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iqReIxqcCkDaoqSoscW2CDc5T8z4Jp3Y)  when tested in phone but in layout editor it is showing correct. I have one more issue it is not loading images at fragment  at first instance but after redirecting to another fragment and loading again it is properly loaded. [First launch](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1x_S-IfQEZSUBtupD1GXX3h3GAMVmnJI_)

Comment: your landscape appears to be constraint right with the given constraint ,  if you need something other than this I can't figure it out, you can make a new post and describe what you want to achieve , so that it will be easy to answer ,and I'm sure you will get a lot of help

Comment: I have edited the question if you could please help.

Comment: I have tested in device it is still the same and sometextviews are misaligned and in landscape it is still the same